Errors related to NullInjectError : No provider for c_!. : Angular 18
I am facing angular error at browser console. This error is related to injection of services. Even though I provided the
'Injector'

before class declaration. Below is the arrnagement of my NgModule class.

import {
  NgxMatDatetimePickerModule, 
  NgxMatNativeDateModule, 
  NgxMatTimepickerModule 
} from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SalesUnitOverviewComponent,
    SalesBookingDetailsComponent,
    NgbdDatepickerRange,
  ],

  // entryComponents: [SalesBookingDetailsComponent],
  
  imports: [
    NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    NgxMatTimepickerModule,
    NgxMatNativeDateModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatDialogModule,    
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    NgbModule,  
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatCardModule   
  ],
  providers:
    [
      SalesUnitOverviewService, PaginationService,
      SalesUnitOverviewComponent, SalesBookingDetailsComponent, HttpClient, HttpClientModule,
      { provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA, useValue: {} },
      { provide: MatDialogRef, useValue: {} }
    ],

  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


Can anybody let me know how can I get rid of this error. Please see the screenshot I am attaching for the reference.

I googled and there were not much of the material available related to exactly the error I am facing!!

I think you should comment out parts of your html to determine what element is causing this.

@user3791775: no even commenting out HTML (main entry HTML) is not fixing this—that entry HTML (app.component.html)  only contains the tag of the main component which renders the page contents. This also still showing the same after commenting that tag
